# Angular Module Loaded But JavaScript Error Says It Is Unavailable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging, replicate

I have server logs that show a client is loading all of the modules required in my `ng-app = M` declaration attached to the `<html>` element. Meaning, all of the dependencies seem to be loaded correctly before my app is declared and initialized.

My app looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('M', ["ui.router",'ui.bootstrap','angular.media','chart.js','ngMessages','ngTouch']);
```

The module reported to my server as the cause of the **`Module Unavailable` error** is `angular.media` even though I can see the following in the server log:

```
XX.XX.X.XXX - - [13/Dec/2017:19:31:24 +0000] "GET /getScript/angular-media.js?v=7.1.7 HTTP/1.1" 200 5172 "https://example.com/home" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.78.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.1.6 Safari/537.78.2"
XX.XX.X.XXX - - [13/Dec/2017:19:31:25 +0000] "GET /getScript/authapp.js?v=9.2 HTTP/1.1" 200 1449 "https://example.com/home" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.78.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.1.6 Safari/537.78.2"
```

I believe the error might have to do with the fact that `angular.media` relies on `ui.router` as well, which may be causing the issue? The `ui.router` is loaded from the cache before reaching the `/home` page.

```
angular.module('angular.media', ["ui.router"])
```

What is causing this issue do you think?

I can load the page fine so I am relying on reported errors to my server from this user but wondering if it is a problem with how I am doing Angular dependency injection.

Angular Url Error: [HERE](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=M&p1=%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.3%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dangular.media%26p1%3D%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.5.3%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253Dangular.media%250Ahttps%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A25%253A159%250Ab%2540https%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A24%253A212%250Ahttps%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A24%253A627%250Ahttps%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A39%253A289%250Aq%2540https%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A359%250Ag%2540https%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A39%253A136%250Ahttps%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A39%253A305%250Aq%2540https%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A359%250Ag%2540https%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A39%253A136%250Aeb%2540https%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A43%253A165%250Ac%2540https%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A20%253A465%250Ayc%2540https%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A21%253A275%250Ade%2540https%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A20%253A84%250Ahttps%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A310%253A123%250Ai%2540https%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252Fjs%252Fjquery.min.js%253A2%253A27718%250AfireWith%2540https%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252Fjs%252Fjquery.min.js%253A2%253A55773%250Aready%2540https%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252Fjs%252Fjquery.min.js%253A2%253A30281%250AK%2540https%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252Fjs%252Fjquery.min.js%253A2%253A30637%0Ahttps:%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:40:98%0Aq@https:%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:7:359%0Ag@https:%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:39:136%0Ahttps:%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:39:305%0Aq@https:%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:7:359%0Ag@https:%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:39:136%0Aeb@https:%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:43:165%0Ac@https:%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:20:465%0Ayc@https:%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:21:275%0Ade@https:%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:20:84%0Ahttps:%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:310:123%0Ai@https:%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fjs%2Fjquery.min.js:2:27718%0AfireWith@https:%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fjs%2Fjquery.min.js:2:55773%0Aready@https:%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fjs%2Fjquery.min.js:2:30281%0AK@https:%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fjs%2Fjquery.min.js:2:30637)

First 10 lines of Angular Media:

```
angular.module('angular.media', ["ui.router"])
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
}])
.directive('angularmedia', [
           '$angularMediaStack',
  function($mediaStack) { 
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
  template:'<div class="someClass"><angularmediabar></angularmediabar><div class="earParagraph"><rewind></rewind><play></play><fastforward></fastforward></div></div>',
controller: function($scope, $element,$attrs) {
```

I am wondering if there is a better way I could be logging and debugging this, since I can't reproduce on my own implementation.

Since the server log indicates the script is being loaded, is it something with how I am trying to record the client-side error? I am using this code:

```
window.onerror = function (message, url, lineNo) {
    try { 
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var formData = new FormData();
         formData.append("message", message);
         formData.append("url", url);
         formData.append("line", lineNo);
       request.open("POST", "/errors");
       request.send(formData);
    } catch (s) {}
    return true;
};
```

Furthermore: this is the order of the script load on `/home`

```
    <script src="https://example.com/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://example.com/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://example.com/js/jquery.scrollex.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://example.com/js/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://example.com/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://example.com/js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://example.com/js/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://example.com/js/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="/getScript/angular-media.js?v=7.1.7"></script>
    <script src="/getScript/Chart.js"></script>
    <script src="/getScript/angular-chart.js"></script>
    <script src="/getScript/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="/getScript/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <!--HTML Content-->
    <script src="/getScript/authapp.js?v=9.2"></script>
    <script src="/getScript/authconfig.js?v=9.2"></script>
    <script src="/getScript/authservices.js?v=9.2"></script>
    <script src="/getScript/authdirectives.js?v=9.2"></script>
    <script src="/getScript/authcontrollers.js?v=9.2.9.2"></script>
    <script>
    app.factory('AboutMe', [function() {
    //fill with PHP derived values
    }]);
</script>
```

The user loads `ui.router` from the landing page and it stays in the cache. Then the IP changes, they go to the homepage, and the error as I have stated **Module Unavailable (angular.media)** is reported to my server using the reporting code I gave above.

Again, I cannot reproduce this error myself and it happens occasionally to various users at different times (never more than one or two at a time) before resolving itself, but it is becoming a big pain.

Please advise as to what could be causing this or how I can better reproduce.

Comment: Angular errors usually have a URL link back to the angular home page to help troubleshoot. Can/Will you post that link?

Comment: @gh9 Thank you! See edit where I included it!

Comment: From my googling there doesnt appear to be an Angular.media module. Will you put the first 10 lines of code from the angular-media file in the question?

Comment: @gh9 It is my own module, thank you so much for your help! Posting now!

Comment: Long shot but, do you have your angular.media script referenced before you bootstrap your angular app?

Comment: @gh9 What do you mean? I don't think so. It's not a dependency of any other module if that's what you mean by "referenced".

Comment: Just making sure that you have all your scripts loading before you app.js script.

Comment: @gh9 yes I do load all the modules/dependencies before app.js

Comment: Why downvote? 

Comment: @SummerDeveloper you can add delay to some scripts [PHP - Sleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) for reproduce the error (change to php script to get js)

Comment: What if you minify and combine all those scripts into single one? That you can be certain that all scripts have loaded, because there is only one big javascript file ...

Comment: If you are using the example domain URL in your application as well, please make sure that they are stable. When I tried the example domain URL (https://example.com/js/angular-ui-router.min.js) they don't
return any response. When no response is returned, angular won't have any modules to load. Hence you would have got this error. Check [plnkr]: https://plnkr.co/edit/WEiuZ2Zamihx0YQP1BD9?p=info